# How to handle two K-1 forms from same company?

Tags: united-states, taxes, schedule-k-1

I have shares in an MLP in two vehicles:

1. A small position from employee stock purchases when I briefly worked for the company
2. A larger position from after I left the company and bought shares on my own in one of my IRA accounts

I am looking right now at two forms K-1 I received. I'm using tax software for the federal filing and it has a section where I can enter K-1 information for Partnerships.

Do I list each separately or should I try to combine the numbers since they are both for an entity with the same tax ID?

And yes, I realize this is probably more trouble than it's worth and I'll probably be selling one or both of these positions off in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type in the forms as they are, separately. That would be the easiest way both to enter the data without any mistakes, and ensure that everything matches properly with the IRS reports.